# How can I assign a name to the figure that a panda boxplot (subplots=True) creates?

Tags: pandas, boxplot, figure

The following easy line of code opens a figure with several subplots (boxplots):

```
objectname = df.plot(kind="box", subplots=True, layout=(3,3))
```

However later i need to adress the above figure to .savefig it in a PDF-File.
Unfortunately, objectname is not the figure name and i don't know how to assign a figure name.

If I write `figname = plt.figure()` in the line before, it only opens an empty figure before the figure with the boxplots...

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you can just use plt.savefig:

```
# dummy data
df = pd.DataFrame({a:np.random.rand(100) for a in 'abcdefghi'})

# plot and save
objectname = df.plot(kind="box", subplots=True, layout=(3,3))
plt.savefig('test.pdf')
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer.
Unfortunately this doesn't solve the problem.
Before I save the figure in a pdf-file, I will create a lot more figures with plots.
Finally at the end of the script i call all the figures by their names and save them together in a .pdf.
So i need to know, how to give the above figure a name that i can call later...

with pdf(report_name) as report:
    report.savefig(torque_plot, bbox_inches="tight", dpi=300)
    report.savefig(pressure_plot, bbox_inches="tight", dpi=300)... etc.